# how to call a batch file with spaces in its path from another batch file and return control to the parent batch file

Tags: cmd, batch-file

I am trying to call a batch file from another batch file and after the second batch file executes , the control should be returned to the first batch file and it should resume execution. 
Currently i am using the following command in my parent batch file:

```
call "cmd /c start /b %ROOT_HOME%\folder1\bin\bat1.bat"
```

This works fine as long as %ROOT_HOME% has a path which doesn't have **spaces** in it.

The above command fails if the path contains spaces in it.

I have tried every combination of **cmd**, **start**, **call** but still unable to achieve the desired result.

Also bat1.bat doesn't have **exit** inside it and it can't be modified.
So using **call** alone only executes the child batch file and doesn't return to the parent batch file.

Comment: why you use so complicated line for the call?Why not simply `call` ?Your call should work like this `call cmd /c start /b "%ROOT_HOME%\folder1\bin\bat1.bat"`

Comment: call only takes a single argument ..hence for executing multiple internal commands , they have to given as a string (within " "). Tried your method , doesn't work. bat1 doesn't get executed.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `call` there at all, since you're spawning the new batch via `cmd` anyway:

```
start "" /b "%ROOT_HOME%\folder1\bin\bat1.bat"
```

Although I wonder why you'd use `start /b` unless you're worried about environment pollution (which can be reverted easily by using `setlocal`/`endlocal` around the call), so `call` should suffice as well:

```
call "%ROOT_HOME%\folder1\bin\bat1.bat"
```

As a general rule: More layers of parsing and execution around something make things only more complicated and rarely makes problems go away. Cf. overuse of `iex` in PowerShell.

Answer (score 2):

what about if you try with short path:

```
for /f %%P in (%ROOT_HOME%) do set SHORT_ROOT_HOME=%%~sP
call "cmd /c start /b  %SHORT_ROOT_HOME%\folder1\bin\bat1.bat"
```

Comment: I was going to suggest same :-)

Answer (score 1):

It should be as simple as this

```
call cmd /c start /b "" "%ROOT_HOME%\folder1\bin\bat1.bat"
```

Comment: Agreed that this would call the batch file but it would open up another console for the child batch file to execute and the child batch file doesn't have EXIT and it can't be modified.Hence console doesn't close automatically.Thereby had to use in combination with cmd and start because they allow the batch to execute within the same console and without another window.

Comment: @r3ap3r Ok, I have edited my answer to reflect your initial command.

Comment: nope, this doesn't work either.Gave it a try.I think "call" can only accept single argument.In your command "call" will take cmd /c as its argument and open up a console which will not do anything nor will it show anything. hence enclosed between " " (as a string).

Comment: I tried it with a dummy file with a space and it worked fine. Is the batch file you are calling ever returning? It shouldn't need an exit if it just falls off the end of the script so to speak. If you manually run it does it ever close?